# Instance does not die

Tags: python

I have 3 devices. Device A communicates with device C. Device B sniffs the connection. My code works fine but I don't understand why does the `decoder` object keeps sniffing the connection after the thread exits (i.e., when the `control` is `True`).

The Decoder class decodes the packets between devices A and C and does not have any looping mechanism (when it is run as a single script, it runs once and then exits).

Here is a simplified version of the code (running on device B) where the problem lies:

```
class Thread_Class(Flag):
    def run(self):
        while(control == False):
            self.parent.object.loop(0, self.handle_packets)

    def handle_packets(self, ...):
        # packet handling code using pcapy library
        packet = ...

        self.parent.decoder = Decoder(self)
        self.parent.decoder.decode(packet)
```

Comment: What is `self.parent.object.loop()`? Does it not loop?

Comment: @NPE it is just a pcapy function to receive packets. The problem does not lie there. If I comment the last 2 lines of the code above, the thread exits.

Comment: You've really not shown enough code to debug this. Is `handle_packets` getting called repeatedly by a single call to `self.parent.object.loop`? Where and how do you set `control` to something non-False? What does `Decoder.decode` do exactly? Can it ever block?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it... I placed an `if control == False` around the last 2 lines